# Multiple Async task implementation

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am working on Android Async tasks. I had tried to implement several Async task in the main class. However, no matter which task i am calling, only the first implementation is loaded. Why is this happen and how can I solve it? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please post your main class code.

Answer (score 0):

I using android annotations, its very simple to implements asynctasks and progressdialog,

references to implements:

http://androidannotations.org/

easy, fast!

Answer (score -1):

I've had similar problems with AsyncTask, and obviously without your code I couldn't tell you what your specific problem is. However, most problems I've seen similar to yours are due to the following couple of points:

> "AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds
>   at the most.) If you need to keep threads running for long periods of
>   time, it is highly recommended you use the various APIs provided by
>   the java.util.concurrent pacakge such as Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor
>   and FutureTask."

Also, if you're expecting the AsyncTasks to run at the same time, you're probably doing it wrong:

> When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single
>   background thread. Starting with DONUT, this was changed to a pool of
>   threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. Starting with
>   HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common
>   application errors caused by parallel execution.
>
> If you truly want parallel execution, you can invoke
>   executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[]) with
>   THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.

Comment: problem solove. It is problem of eclipse, it cannot run the updated program. It works well after restart.